# Ubuntu: Mounted a WebDAV share, shows up in Nautilus, but where is it in the filesystem?

Tags: ubuntu, network-shares, webdav

I'd like to create a simple command line script that will copy some files from ~/myfiles to files on a WebDAV-mounted filesystem over a network connection. I can easily click on places and bookmarks, enter the password/username combo and it'll mount from within Nautilus, but I can't find the location of the filesystem anywhere with the mount command so I can't very well do anything non-GUI to manipulate files.

Will I have to find a way to manually mount the share to a mount point, or is there a way to get it to show up in Nautilus and the filesystem at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@andreas-h](https://superuser.com/users/104415/andreas-h) noted in 2014, these days you'll find your WebDAV shares mounted under `/run/user/1000/gvfs`, where `1000` is the user ID of your user.

**Answer valid until sometime between 2009 and 2014:**

Afaik, shares mounted via the 'Connect to Server' tool in Nautilus end up under ~/.gvfs. However, there were some issues navigating webdav shares mounted via this tool, see this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gvfs/+bug/340359).

Comment: this is not valid any more in recent ubuntu versions. on 13.10, it's in `/run/user/1000/gvfs`, where `1000` is the user ID of your user.

Answer (score 0):

You want to try FuseDav:

```
sudo apt-get install fusedav
```

Then follow these instructions:

> http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/fusedav.1.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.